# React - Re-rendering of a graph when data is updated ( Amcharts )

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amcharts, amcharts4

I am developing a react application where I need the force-directed-tree to update its data on a button click. I have tried doing it with an example of color change in below link

https://codesandbox.io/s/amcharts-example-e1f3o

But here, the entire chart is refreshed to change the color of a single node( First ). Is it possible to make the chart not refresh completely when it re-renders, so that it looks like only 1 node is re-rendering

I asked this question in the amcharts github issues section and they said that amcharts library does not support that kind of re-render

So can any other trick ( not related to amcharts but using fundamental react concepts) be applied here so the refresh of the component is not visible and it looks like it has instantly changed the color

Comment: Any progress on this? I'm facing to same issue.